# ImageButton inside ListView onClick() method inside customer adapter

Tags: android, listview, uibutton, adapter

Method onClick() is work only when position == 0? Why?

```
public class mySCAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements OnClickListener {
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
LayoutInflater inflater;
public mySCAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to) {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;

    if( convertView != null )
        v = convertView;
    else
        v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.add_program_ex_list_item, parent, false);
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) v
            .findViewById(R.id.add_program_exercise_list);
    button.setTag(position);
    button.setOnClickListener(this); 


    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "It works, pos=" + v.getTag());

}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageButton inside ListView onClick()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271815/imagebutton-inside-listview-onclick)

Comment: Try returning `v` instead of `super.getView()`

Comment: when i return v- onClick() work fine, but data in list view does not showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not overriding `getView()` properly. It needs to be something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;
    if (convertView != null)
        v = convertView;
    else
        v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.add_program_ex_list_item, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
    textView.setText(getItem(position));

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.add_program_exercise_list);
    button.setTag(position);
    button.setOnClickListener(this); 

    return v;
}
```

Comment: it will be a solution, but how to setText, if a know position?

Comment: `textView.setText(getItem(position));` doesn't work? Or what do you mean?

Comment: The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: Tried casting it? I don't know what objects you are using... `textView.setText((String) getItem(position));`

Comment: i tried it, it does not work

Comment: tv.setText((String)getItem(position)); ClassCastExeption android...SqliteCursor

Comment: Well, convert it accordingly. `SQLiteCursor cursor = getItem(position);` `tv.setText(cursor.getString(0));` or whatever column you want

Comment: SQLiteCursor cursor = (SQLiteCursor)getItem(position);
  tv.setText(cursor.getString(1)); it is solution,thank you

Answer (score 0):

set cursor position like

instead of

```
button.setTag(position)
```

you do

```
button.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
```

where you can set cursor in your constructor.

```
this.cursor = c;
```